# Border CSS not working properly with VF page rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, css, renderas, getcontentaspdf

Hi I'm trying to display rounded borders in a VF page using the below style on a individual div and a tr inside a table separately.

```
 style="text-align: left;border: 1px solid black !important;border-radius: 10px !important;"
```

This css works fine when I render the VF page but when I render the VF page as Pdf the borders are not rounded hence the border-radius is not working in render as Pdf. How can we make the css work in the VF page rendered as PDF.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF engine that Salesforce still use AFAIK is [Flying Saucer](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html) and that is far behind current CSS standards including to my knowledge not supporting rounded borders. So I'm afraid you will have to live with square corners.